# iPhone native app with HTML and CSS in UIWebView

Tags: html, css, iphone, xcode, uiwebview

I have added my Html, CSS and image files in the bundle of my Xcode application.

In my project I loaded the Html content in the UIWebView like this,

```
NSString *htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil];
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSURL *Url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlString];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:Url];
```

The Html file is loaded, but CSS and Images are missing.

In my Html file add the CSS and images as follows,

```
<link href="/css/myCss.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

   <img class"icon" alt="" src="/img/icon.png" />
```

Need help to resolve this problem.

Comment: try adding tow dots before first '/' in addresses eg. "../css/myCss.css" .

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal: Just tried. But not working

Comment: Does it work if you remove the folders in the paths? So that /css/myCss.css becomes myCss.css and /img/icon.png becomes icon.png. I believe that's how i got it to work in my app a while ago, despite the fact that the files were in folders & groups.

Comment: I have tried that too, but result is same

Comment: Oh, sorry, just checked the code, and the app i was thinking about didn't even use an WebView :/

Answer (score 1):

First, get rid of the initial / in the file paths in the html so you have:

```
<link href="css/myCss.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<img class"icon" alt="" src="img/icon.png" />
```

Make sure when you are adding the files you are using the Folders option: "Create folder references for any added folders".

The code loading the html in the webview can be simplified to look like:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil];

[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

I also suggest putting your html assets into a "www" or "html" folder instead of the base folder.